# Whare are the difference between set and with in jinja

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am beginner in computer science and trying to use python flask framework to create a webserver.

In the tutorials, I have seen the below jinja usage in the HTML which are

1. `{% set a = somefunction() %}`
2. `{% with a = somefunction() %}`

May I know what are the differences? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may use `{% set %}` to define a variable, the `{% with %}` statement additionally creates a new scope which can be ended using the `{% endwith %}` statement.

For example:

```
{% with myvar=1 %}
    ...
{% endwith %}
```

`myvar` will only be available before the corresponding `endwith`.

You can also use `with` to create a local scope:

```
{% with %}
    {% set myvar=1 %}
    ...
{% endwith %}
```

`myvar` will only be available within the given scope.

You can find information about these statements [here](https://www.webforefront.com/django/usebuiltinjinjastatements.html) (the examples shown here were taken from there also).

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside a `{% with %}` statement are restricted to that particular statement, while variables created via `{% set %}` are accessible from anywhere in the template (they are global).

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template("{% set a = 'Global' %}{% with a = 'Local' %}{{ 'First a is ' + a +'\n' }}{% endwith %}{{ 'Second a is ' + a }}")
>>> print(t.render())
First a is Local  
Second a is Global
```